# Windows Server 2012 Interactive Services Detection does not work

Tags: windows-server-2012

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am running the program FireDeamon to run my game services, but upon clicking the pop-up message it'll just either bring me to a blue or black screen. I already tried setting the value in the registry to: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows\NoInteractiveServices=0` and rebooting the machine but this did not work, I even tried it twice.

So is there an clear and working solution for this issue? If not, could someone please provide me with a good working alternative for FireDeamon.

Comment: The "Interactive Services Detection" service is off by default in Windows 7, and I'm not sure whether it even exists in Windows 2012 R2.  You can use the Services administrative tool to see whether it exists, and if it does, to start it and/or reconfigure it to start automatically.

Comment: As shown in this image: https://i.gyazo.com/f566f47da8ba3fb417c57c834f32443f.png this is already enabled and set to start automatically, but we still get a black/blue screen upon entering session 0. I also have noticed that the pop-up never pops up again after it has been closed once.

Comment: You should also check that the service you're trying to run (FireDaemon?) has the "Allow service to interact with desktop" option enabled.

Comment: These are already checked, it still doesn't work. We tried all these options but it still ends up showing a black screen. Image shows: https://i.gyazo.com/0bbb2705a3ae5fa8cba2c9cf4ee7e534.png